# C++ destroy_tree pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I have a problem with destroy_tree function for deleting a tree in C++. Compiler says `*** glibc detected *** <path>: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f37590d3778 ***`. Here is my `destroy_tree` function:

```
void Tree::destroy_tree(node** parent) {

if ( (*parent) != NULL ) {

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ELEMS; i++) {
        destroy_tree( &((*parent)->leaves[i]) );
    }

    if ( (*parent)->zone_id != NULL ) {
        delete (*parent)->zone_id;
        (*parent)->zone_id = NULL;
    }

    delete (*parent);
    (*parent) = NULL;
}
```

And here is structure:

```
struct node {

    int* zone_id;
    node* leaves [NUM_ELEMS];

    node() : leaves() {} //setting all leaves pointers to NULL

};
```

Pointers initialization (in other function):

```
    (*parent)->leaves[value]->zone_id = new int;
    *((*parent)->leaves[value]->zone_id) = zone_id;
```

I just can't see where it fails...

Comment: You're not following Rule of Three (or Five). And it is a badly designed `node` class anyway.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? It will tell you where the crash is, so you know which of the `delete` you do is the culprit.

Comment: The error is in this line: `delete (*parent)->zone_id;` whenever I comment it, program works fine, but not performing any delete operations over zone_id pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try It.. I think this "if" should be include all code Not only recursion destroy_tree

```
void Tree::destroy_tree(node** parent) 
{
if ( (*parent) != NULL )  //I think this "if" should be include all code Not only recursion destroy_tree
  {
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ELEMS; i++) 
    {enter code here
        destroy_tree( &((*parent)->leaves[i]));
    }
   if ( (*parent)->zone_id != NULL )   //the (*parent) should not be NULL
    {
        delete (*parent)->zone_id;
        (*parent)->zone_id = NULL;
    }
    delete (*parent);  //the (*parent) should not be NULL
    (*parent) = NULL;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my poor english